# Publish App on Intuit Marketplace

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to publish this app on the Intuit Marketplace:

http://www.jmawebtechstore.com/nopcommerce-quickbooks-online-connex

My app has a settings page in the admin of nopCommerce where the user exports orders to QBO. I just need the connect to QuickBooks option. in the marketplace's publish tab, is create Intuit connection the right option for me? Do I need to create a MVC page in the root of the website that allows the users to sync orders?

Comment: The Intuit Partner Platform/Intuit AppCenter is for *hosted SaaS applications only*. If this is a plugin that people buy for a one-time purchase price, and then install on their own servers, then you *do not meet the requirements for building on top of AppCenter/IPP, and your application won't work* and certainly won't be published by Intuit. Are you sure you meet these requirements? It doesn't look like it from the description on your website...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joseph,
The requirements for an Intuit Anywhere Application and for listing on the Intuit App Center are listed here: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0080_FAQ

regards,
Jarred